# Javascript function not looping properly over items

Tags: javascript

This is my JS that adds evenet listeners to every ideanode:

```
var ideanodes = [...document.querySelectorAll('.ideanode')];
ideaNodesListRefresh();
function ideaNodesListRefresh(){
 ideanodes = [...document.querySelectorAll('.ideanode')];
 console.log("refreshed")
 ideanodes.forEach(ideanode => {
   var maintxt = ideanode.querySelector(".maintext");
   var titleArrow = ideanode.querySelector(".title-arrow");
   var mainArrow = ideanode.querySelector(".maintxt-arrow");
   var comments = ideanode.querySelector(".comments");

   titleArrow.addEventListener('click', function() {
     maintxt.classList.toggle("hidden");
     mainArrow.classList.toggle("hidden");
     if (comments.classList.contains("hidden")) {;
     } else {
       comments.classList.toggle("hidden");
     };
   });

   mainArrow.addEventListener("click", function() {
     comments.classList.toggle("hidden");
   });
 });
};
```

the function gets fired at the end of the creation of a new ideanode:

```
function createNeed(user) {
    if (user==user1) {
       var newNeed = document.createElement('div');
       newNeed.className = "ideanode";
       var newNeedHeader = document.createElement('div');
       newNeedHeader.className = "ideanodeheader"; 
       var newNeedHeaderText = document.createTextNode('Need');
       newNeedHeader.appendChild(newNeedHeaderText);
       newNeed.appendChild(newNeedHeader);
       var newNeedContent = document.createElement('div');
       newNeedContent.className = "content";
       newNeed.appendChild(newNeedContent);
       var needTitle = document.createElement('div');
       needTitle.className="title";
       var needTitleH3 = document.createElement('h2');
       var titleText = document.createTextNode('Title');
       needTitleH3.appendChild(titleText); 
       needTitleH3.setAttribute('onclick', 'this.focus();');
       needTitleH3.setAttribute('contenteditable', 'True');
       newNeedContent.appendChild(needTitleH3);
       var downArrow0 = document.createElement('i');
       downArrow0.classList = 'fas fa-sort-down title-arrow';
       newNeedContent.appendChild(downArrow0);
       var maintext = document.createElement('div');
       maintext.classList = 'maintext hidden';
       textareaMain = document.createElement("textarea");
       textareaMain.className = "maintextinput";
       textareaMain.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Text');
       maintext.appendChild(textareaMain);
       newNeedContent.appendChild(maintext);
       var downArrow1 = document.createElement('i');
       downArrow1.classList = 'fas fa-sort-down maintxt-arrow hidden';
       newNeedContent.appendChild(downArrow1);
       var comments = document.createElement('div');
       comments.classList = "comments hidden";
       textareaComments = document.createElement("textarea");
       textareaComments.className = "commentsinput";
       textareaComments.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Comments');
       comments.appendChild(textareaComments);
       newNeedContent.appendChild(comments);
       newNeed.appendChild(newNeedContent);
       var container = document.querySelector('#needsuser1');
       var lastNeed = document.querySelector(".ideanode:last-child");

       lastNeed.parentNode.insertBefore(newNeed, lastNeed.nextSibling);

       ideaNodesListRefresh();

    } else {
        console.log("user2")
    }
}
```

But when I add a new ideanode the function doesn't work properly and the eventlisteners only work for the newest ideanode.
This is a codepen of what I'm doing: https://codepen.io/ricodon1000/pen/PoPeXJL
I would like to simply add eventlisteners to the arrows of the new ideanode and have all of the arrows of all of the ideanodes work.

Comment: I dont know how to use your pen. Can you please create a minimal working example?

Comment: This is the minimal working example, if i remove anything it doesn't really work. As I said in the post I would simply like to have the downward arrows open up new sections of the boxes, just like they do before you press the "create new" button in the upper right corner. When you add a new one from the button, the original boxes' arrows stop working though.